Kafka Connect in Docker and AWS ECS
I have Kafka Connect running in docker on AWS ECS. There are three ECS tasks running Kafka Connect. There are 110 connectors. Every so often it just hangs - ECS reports task as healthy, the last log line shows no errors but Kafka Connect UI and the API calls just time out.
I'm struggling to work out what the best approach is - should I add more tasks or more resources to the existing tasks? Is there a way to see how spread out the connectors are across the three ECS tasks?
